# Plugin.BLE(1.3.0) for xamarin.Forms not getting data byte in Characteristic

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing Forms app where I am connecting to the device and need to fetch the data. I am able to search devices, connect and get the services, but for service, I am unable to read data from its Characteristic.

```
 Services = await device.GetServicesAsync();
                try
                {
                    selectedServiceGuid = Services[6].Id;
                    Service = await device.GetServiceAsync(selectedServiceGuid);    
                }
                catch (TimeoutException ext)
                {
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                } 

                Characteristic = await Service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse("f000aa41-0451-4000-b000-000000000000")); 

                if (Characteristic.CanRead)
                {
                    var c = await Characteristic.ReadAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(c.ToArray());
                }

                if (Characteristic.CanUpdate)
                {
                    Characteristic.ValueUpdated += (s, ee) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("characteristic.ValueUpdated");
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            UpdateDisplay(Characteristic);
                        });
                    };
                  await  Characteristic.StartUpdatesAsync();

                }
```

Getting byte[] 0 at all index,
 using await Characteristic.ReadAsync() to read.
Anyone is facing/faced the same problem?

Comment: After Bluetooth establishes a connection, data transmission needs to have a certain time interval. A null value is read if it is read immediately after the connection. Therefore, it is necessary to re-connect the data after a certain period of time. The interval can be modified by yourself.

Comment: Problem is solved. Thanks for your concern Junior. In my case to read the value from the device, I need to enable that particular service by writing '01' to the device. 

 Characteristic = await Service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse("f000aa42-0451-4000-b000-000000000000"));
await Characteristic.WriteAsync(data);

Comment: Greate ,different equipment requirements will be different,this is a good question.